# Is it possible to use ternary operator in a strongly typed Repeater control to bind data?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am creating an admin page for my website, and I added a button with which I can unlocked locked users (who failed to provide a valid password for 10 times).

I want to disable this button if the user is not locked. I am using a strongly typed Repeater control for that:

```
<asp:Repeater ItemType="Xamlalo.Pages.Admin.UserDetails" SelectMethod="GetUsers" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
            <td><%# Item.Name %></td>
            <td><%# Item.Roles %></td>
            <td><%# Item.Locked %></td>
            <td><%# Item.Online %></td>
            <td><button type="submit" name="unlock" value="<%# Item.Name %>" <%# Item.Locked ? "disabled" : "" %>>Feloldás</button></td>
            <td><button type="submit" name="delete" value="<%# Item.Name %>">Törlés</button></td>
           </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The problem is that the the ternary expression doesn't bind, and I won't have the "disabled" attribute on my button. If `Item.Locked` evaluates to true, I want to add the disabled attribute to the button. I've tried with `<%= (bool)Eval("Locked") ? "disabled" : "" >`, but to no avail. I suspect the problem is that with `<%#` directive, I can only bind the value/properties of `Item`, not arbitrary string values.

```
<button type="submit" name="unlock" value="<%# Item.Name %>" <%# Item.Locked ? "disabled" : "" %>>Feloldás</button>
```

Comment: Your ternary operator is correct. Display the value of `Item.Locked` and see what it is.

Comment: Found the problem, my ternary expression is wrong, results "disabled" if the the user is locked, should have been `!Item.Locked`, so it did the opposite as it was supposed to do.